# Matching regex with keyword in a perl script

Tags: regex, perl

perl regex is very powerful while using in text content unfortunately I don't get the output what I have expected with my code by doing wrong matches.

In this matches we have `n` of matches with MBBS and the keyword `practitioner`.

**Sample Input:**

> Sample text - There are no statistically significant direct effects of prior behavior on practitioner current crop loss, measured by Mr. Srivatsan MBBS M.D. log of amount of crop loss. Third, although we cover a number and given by ***Mr. Sankaranarayan MBBS possible explanations for what practitioner determines practitioner*** of crop loss, it is possible that there may be other unobserved, time-varying household characteristics that influence whether a household experience a crop loss. If that is the case the causality from crop loss to fertility decisions may not hold.

**My Code:**

```
my $txtfile = "sample.txt";

readFileinString($txtfile, \$string);
my $keyword = "practitioner";

if($string=~m/Mr.\s+(\w+)\s+MBBS(.*?)\s+practitioner\s+/i)
{
    print "$&\n";
}
```

***Code Output:***

```
Mr. Srivatsan MBBS M.D. log of amount of crop loss. Third, although we cover a number and given by Mr. Sankaranarayan MBBS possible explanations for what practitioner
```

***Expected Output:***

```
Mr. Sankaranarayan MBBS possible explanations for what practitioner determines practitioner
```

Could someone have any experience doing on this way and provide suggestions please.

Comment: The pattern will not match this string: "Mr. X MBBS is a non-practitioner." Perhaps you mean `\bpractitioner\b` instead of `\s+practitioner\s+`? See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`.

I think you want

```
if ($string =~ /(Mr\.\s+(\w+)\s+MBBS(?:(?!MBBS).)*\s+practitioner\s+)/si) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

You can add to the inner part of `(?:(?!MBBS).)*`. For example, you might prefer `(?:(?!Mr\.|MBBS).)*`.

Comment: awesome. got it ... +1

Comment: May I know if we can do in reverse search from the keyword `practitioner` `lookaround` and `lookbehind`.

Comment: Perl doesn't support variable-width lookbehind (so you can't look for `practitioner` preceded by `MBBS`), and you'd still have to solve exactly the same problem if it did.

Comment: I have one query on this, that the regex matches the last `practitioner` how it is possible? `Mr. Sankaranarayan MBBS possible explanations for what practitioner determines practitioner`. In this case the keyword `practitioner` matches in twice. The first one not considered and then the second one got matched...

Comment: Sorry I am not clear and excuse please... `(Mr\.\s+(\w+)\s+MBBS(?:(?!MBBS).)*\s+practitioner` its equal to this only `Sankaranarayan MBBS possible explanations for what practitioner` how it matches the second one....? that is `Sankaranarayan MBBS possible explanations for what practitioner determines **practitioner**`

Comment: You are mistaken. For the passage you provided, the code I provided outputs `Mr. Sankaranarayan MBBS possible explanations for what practitioner determines practitioner`.

Comment: Why are you using "MBBS" and not "Mr."? `m/Mr.\s+(\w+)\s+MBBS(?:(?!Mr.).)*?\s+practitioner\s+/i` Wouldn't using the start of the pattern be more logical?

Comment: @shawncory, Depends what the OP wants, but they didn't specify. The answer already suggests there are other possible solutions, and even points out that `Mr\.` could be included.

Comment: @ikegami I was thinking more of  a generalized solution. `m{$start_pattern(?:(?!$start_pattern).)*?$end_pattern}`

Comment: @shawncorey, It's far more common to want *start !end end* or *start !(start|end) end*, but that's not applicable here. They're not trying to parse markup/quoted/etc

Comment: @ikegami The OP is trying to parse; they just don't realize it.

Comment: @shawnhcorey, Of course they are. But thry can't use the patterns usually used to parse balanced text (markup/quoted/etc) because that's not what they have